# How to Play Youtube search results consequently

Tags: youtube

I am struggling to understand how to solve this "small" issue in Youtube:

1. I put a keyword in a search bar and hit enter.
2. I get all the "related" videos below.
3. I hit the first one and watch it.
4. I finished watching it.

Now, I want to see next relevant video but I have to hit "back" arrow in a browser or re-enter the keyword in search because all the videos presented on the right are relevant to my previous searches/plays but not to current one.

My question is: How can I play all the related search results consequently without hitting the back button or re-inserting the keyword - I use bluetooth and I am not close to the PC while watching/listening to videos.

Please, any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

One way you could do this, is to create a playlist.
[image: descriptive image]

Just click the three vertical dots and create a new playlist. Add other relevant videos to this playlist as well.

I know it's a little tedious!